# How to start a page with a modal window based on code behind condition

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I need to start an vb.aspx page with a modal window if a codebehind query condition is true,
how to achive that dear experts!!!

Comment: Make an Ajax call on the window.load event to check the condition.

Comment: Not familiar with ajax, vb please, if ajax submit example for see if i get it!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
//Code behind

if(DBConditionIsTrue())
{
    ScriptManger.RegisterStartupScript(btnExample,btnExample.GetType(),"scriptName","window.open("vb.aspx", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");")
}
```